# Installing ubuntu 18.04 without turning off the RST

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, nvidia, uefi

laptop={gpu: NVIDA RTX 3060, CPU: i7, RAM: 32GB, EFI, RST: enabled}

I have the RST enabled on my lap-top and already know how to safely change it to AHCI but I don't want to do that! Mainly because it works flawlessly with RST! It boots up in less than 3 seconds! It chews up the hardest visual and performance tasks! And when I turn RST off, I see how it degrades the performance!

In spite off all of that, but I hate working with windows, especially when it comes to embedded systems which is a huge part of my job! yeah it is awesome for gaming but when it comes to work, Linux based systems are such a doll!

Now, I read in some articles that Ubuntu 18.04 can do with RST but not sure about it. Can anybody help me to install ubuntu (any version is fine) without turning RST off?

And of course, the VM choice is not my option at all!

Comment: AFAIK, (1) both "Intel RST" or "RAID" modes aren't yet compatible and (2) performance should be the same with AHCI.

Comment: Thanks, on performance: to my experience, it is different

Comment: You have a simple choice: Learn to love Windows using RST, or learn to love Linux using AHCI. If you want RST for Linux, contact Intel and tell them so. It's their decision, not ours.

Answer (score 4):

There is no Ubuntu setup that functions with Intel RST at this time.

Ubuntu does not support the Intel RST functionality ("Intel Soft-RAID" as it's called by some).  18.04 is no exception.